# Official bots to have different colour username to enable users to differentiate between them and other bots/users

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat, design, chatbot

To stop confusion and to prevent some abuse, I think it would be good for certain bots to have a different colour from normal users (like moderators do from normal users), I think green would be a good colour. This would prevent things like people pretending to be bots and tricking users into doing things such as going to malicious websites (a good example would be if someone created a fake SmokeDetector account and pretended to be it in chat and then tricked people into going somewhere bad by reporting a fake spam question which in fact takes you to another site that perhaps looks like the SE site where the spam would be but has one of its letters different or something), and people thinking bots are in fact real people and trying to engage them in conversation and thus causing lots of confusion...

So I think that official bots like SmokeDetector should be registered as official bots and have a green 'trusted' colour to their names so that one can differentiate between them and other bots/users.

To prevent request spamming only moderators should be allowed to mark a bot as 'official'.

Comment: Great idea, but how people be sure that a bot is a bot when it is registered? Or that the account stays controlled by a bot?

Comment: That's a good point.  I think Panda is getting at things like "smoke detector" and "meta watch" like bots.  Not every bot.  At least on AU, those are moderator controlled, and as such will remain very official.  I don't think they're talking about registering every user's bot.

Comment: SmokeDetector is far from an official bot. Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: These wouldn't just be any old bots, they would be proper used ones like SmokeDetector, the creators would be unlikely to do anything bad. And if they did, then there would be repercussions.

Comment: SmokeDetector is a user-created bot, and if you're wanting to apply this to something like that, we'd have to have some sort of process to request "official" status and then have us review it. I don't think any of us cares enough to do that, and we'd probably just end up with more "I created bot, I can haz official status now plz" requests than anything worth looking at.

Comment: That's also a good point.  You probably would get flooded with bad "bot registration requests."  That's a problem I didn't see before it got there.  What about a setting so moderators for a given site can mark a bot as "site sponsored".  No application process, just a marker for "this one is run by mods"

Comment: @animuson: Perhaps only users with, say, 10k rep would be allowed to 'nominate' bots for 'official status'. Or you could even only allow mods to do it.

Comment: It would probably be that only mods could mark a bot as official, so no ability to request, and thus no spam. I also still think that this is a good idea because it would stop some trickery and confusion which is currently possibly, like I could make a new account called SmokeDetector and be able to trick some into going to malicious links (probably quite a lot of people).

Comment: You might trick me once ... and after that I probably flag the message and RO's might kick those accounts...

Comment: Just because it's possible doesn't mean people will do it. It's almost impossible for legitimate spammers to get into chat, because they not only need to create an account, but also reach 20 reputation somewhere. Which just leaves actual users. And I can't say I've ever personally run across an *actual* user with 20 reputation intentionally posting a link to a malicious site anywhere, even outside of chat. It sounds like you're trying to prevent something that isn't a problem.

Comment: @rene: But the original tricking would have been preventable, and you might end up getting ransomeware.

Comment: But my name isn't Paranoid

Comment: @animuson: On some sites it is not that hard to reach 20 rep. Like if you have a little bit of imagination on Worldbuilder you could probably get quite high like I got to several hundred like that there... :D

Comment: But it still requires you to *actually do something*, and even something that's actually positive and gains reputation. Spammers wouldn't do that. It still requires an actual user behind the account, and I just don't see someone spending the time just to create a look-alike bot to post malicious links.

Comment: @animuson: Well, some spammers could get a little more determination, plus they could get one account that upvotes the others so it could be easier for them to get enough rep to quickly put some bad stuff in chat.

Comment: Why all this fuss about bots? A hypothetical spammer with 20 rep can name themselves "Shadow Wizard", copy Shadow Wizard's avatar and bio, then come to a chat room and post malicious links with "LOL, what a story" [or a better imitation of Shadow's style]. If you want absolute safety, unplug the network cable.

Comment: @Norm sadly enough, these days even unplugging the network cable does not grant absolute safety: http://www.latinpost.com/articles/5971/20140116/mission-possible-the-nsa-can-hack-internet-isolated-computers-including-the-mexican-police-using-secret-radio-technology.htm (and there are other ways, e.g. [another one](http://www.wnd.com/2014/06/computers-now-hacked-without-internet/) which looks more reliable actually)

Comment: ... Did Gelidus (help) spark this proposal?

Comment: Related / renewed proposal now that there is a designated technology for this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369313/can-other-bots-have-an-identifying-label-too-even-user-run-bots

Answer (score 10):

"Official" implies "belongs to Stack Exchange" or "operated by Stack Exchange".

None of the bots you mention belong to SE or are being operated by SE, they were created by ordinary users, some not even moderators, and being operated by them.

I don't see any point giving those bots different color. Those who are not familiar with the bots should not click their links anyway, same way common sense tells us not to click "click here to see [celebrity name here] naked". Those who are familiar with the bots can detect the different avatar, and if the impersonation is complete, including avatar, report to the team and they will nuke the bot account and possibly whoever operated it. Case solved. :)

Comment: Also worth mentioning that chat doesn't have a supported API. All bots (except feeds) operate based on reversed engineered http and web sockets interactions.

Comment: And the bots by SE can usually be recognized as such (Feeds, Stack-Exchange, Community), while users may run bots without registering them.

Comment: Wait... so that link that said to click here to see Angela Merkel naked was... not real?

Comment: @StephanBijzitter depends, what you got when clicking it? ;)

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Why the heck is the first person coming into your mind when you read the words "celebrity" and "naked" "Angela Merkel"!?!? o.O

Comment: @Byte actually, there [was a big fuss around it](http://www.buzzfeed.com/ellievhall/angela-merkel-nude-photo-may-not-be-of-angela-merkel#.ot1zzN1wL5) so probably it's still imprinted in Stepahn's mind. :D

Comment: I think it's a good sign that I haven't noticed any of this...

Comment: Oh my god, I just wrote a name that was on the top of my head (was just reading an article about Mother Merkel wanting Turkey to join the EU sooner than later)! @ShadowWizard I cannot unsee!

Comment: ROFL, you clicked the link! @Stephan :-D

Answer (score 5):

There are only probably 3 or 4 official bots I know of, the **Community** account, the **Feeds** bot, the **Stack-Exchange** bot that informs you about room title/topic/tag/owner changes and maybe bots like the one posting questions tagged `ubuntu` from Unix&Linux into the AskUbuntu General Room.

All (?) others like SmokeDetector are regular user accounts.

You would have someone to review all those accounts and check whether their owners run useful and accepted bots through them. This is not only much work, it's also useless, because not all bot owners will apply their accounts for a registration and not all once registered bots always have to be used by actual bots or by the reviewed, non-malicious implementation.

I'd rather stay with the current state, where bot account owners should make that clear by either a well-chosen name (like mine who is called "ByteBOT") or state the fact that it's a bot and who the owner is in the profile's about-me section. Everything voluntarily.

Comment: I still think that there should be better bot control. They shouldn't be able to just pretend to be people, nor should others be able to impersonate them.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda How will you make sure a regular account is no bot? How can you, the other way round, make sure that a once registered friendly bot account is not now running malicious code or taken over by a human again? It isn't really possible.