# Can other bots have an identifying label, too? Even user-run bots?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, information-display, robots, user-labels

Now that [the Community user is going to be explicitly labelled as a bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369071/please-use-the-new-mod-staff-badge-tech-to-identify-community-as-a-bot), how about adding the same label to other bot accounts, too?

There is an old request for *essentially* the same thing, but at the time, the labels were not a feature of the site, so it proposed using different colors:
[Official bots to have different colour username to enable users to differentiate between them and other bots/users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268082/official-bots-to-have-different-colour-username-to-enable-users-to-differentiate)

One of the replies there alleges that there are just a few bot accounts, but that is not (any longer?) true:
[Why does Chat have so many negative user IDs?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410953/why-does-chat-have-so-many-negative-user-ids/410955#410955)

However, I would like to take this one step further, and request a process for adding this label to designated bot accounts more generally. There's a number of **user-run bots** in the system; it would make sense for these to be able to have the same label, too.  A well-known one is [Smoke Detector](https://charcoal-se.org/) but there are many more in chat, and some of them have activity on the sites as well (leaving comments, for example).

Comment: Not really relevant right now, as chat has no labels. If and when it will have, this request will become relevant. Unless you mean show bot label in the main/meta site profiles of  user-run chat bots?

Comment: But chat users have parent users with profiles you can look at, and it's one of the few places where you can find something out about a user whose identity you are investigating. I'd regard this as relevant even now.

Comment: IMO there should be some visual difference between Official bots and community bots,

Comment: According to [Catija’s comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369071/please-use-the-new-mod-staff-label-tech-to-identify-community-as-a-bot#comment1235358_369847) they aren’t going to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At this time, there's nothing on the roadmap that would include this work.  I'll add it to a features request list but I don't want to get your hopes up - this would be pretty far down my list of important stuff to work on first, though I think there's merit in the idea. :-)